# Extending the Charme Interpreter by Defining Null and Null?

Tags: python, scheme, interpreter

I need to help extending the Charme interpreter and defining the **null** and **null?** primitives that behave similarly to the primitive Scheme procedures. I know I can use Python's None value to represent null.

Comment: Presumably related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5494973/2509 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5494256/2509.

Comment: You're not getting a lot of interest for these questions, perhaps there are not many people using this thing. One thing you could do is [offer a bounty](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/), though you would need to accumulate some rep first. Have you considered *answering* some questions? You don't need to be a world class expert, just looks for ones you know the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a homework question:
http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs1120-f09/ps/ps7/

A few pointers:

- How is the empty list (aka null) represented as a Python value?
- Which function is used to extend the environment?